# Right Aligning Decimal String in C

Tags: c

I have 2 decimal strings with only 2 decimal points.These strings are printed one below the other.I need a way to properly align these strings such that these strings are right aligned.Like this

```
256.60
 59.00
```

---

```
char max[20]="";
char cmax[20]="";
strcat(max,"STB Amount: ");
strcat(max,stbamount);
strcat(cmax,"PKG Amount: ");        
strcat(cmax,pkgamount);
//strcat(cmax,".00");
prn_write_text(max,strlen(max),1);
prn_write_text(cmax,strlen(cmax),1);
```

Here `prn_write_text` is an API Call to use the thermal printer.24 is central point in the paper.I tried appending some spaces(see code below),it wont work.

---

```
    int yyer=24+(24-strlen(stbamount));

    int c=0;
    for (c=0;c<yyer;yyer++)
    {
       strcat(max," ");
    }
```

Please advice.

UPDATE:

***3.3.1.6 int prn_write_text ( unsigned char ∗ text2, int len, int font )

This API Function is used to prints the text .
Parameters
text2,: Description: pointer to the buffer from which the text to be  
 printed. Type: INPUT

len,: Description: length of the text. Type: INPUT

font,: Description: font of the the text presently there are two fonts are 
supported.(1 and 2 fonts).

Type: INPUT***

***UPDATE:***

I tried increasing the buffer size ,still in the case of these values the last zero is being cut-off

```
    char amount1[10]="";
    char amount2[10]="";
    char dummyamount[20]="";
    float bamt1,bamt2,amt1,amt2;
    float balance1,balance2;
    char sbal[20]="";
    char pbal[20]="";
    char x1 = balance1;
    char x2 = balance2;
    int tmp1 = balance1 * 100;
    balance1 = tmp1 / 100.0;
    int tmp2 = balance2 * 100;
    balance2 = tmp2 / 100.0;
    char buf1[25]="";
    char buf2[25]="";

    snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%.2f", balance1);
    printf("\nbuffer1 ---------->%f\n",buf1);   
    snprintf(buf2, sizeof buf2, "%.2f", balance2);
    printf("\nbuffer2 ---------->%f\n",buf2);



      memset(max,0,sizeof(max));
      memset(cmax,0,sizeof(cmax));
      snprintf(max, 20,"STB Balance:%8s", buf1);
      snprintf(cmax, 20,"PKG Balance:%8s", buf2);
      prn_write_text(max,strlen(max),1);
      prn_write_text(cmax,strlen(cmax),1);
```

In case of values like `-2003.30` i only get `-2003.0`.I don't know if the cutting logic above or the `snprintf` is causing issues.

Comment: make use of optional minimum field width with `printf()`.

Comment: It all depends on the specifics of how `prn_write_text` is implemented, with a minimum width or whatever. Failing to know whats possible with it, we can't help you.

Comment: Not specific to C, nor is it elegant .. but what I do is to create a string of MAX chars (10 in this case) and fill with my 'padding' character.  I'll demonstrate with "0" as its easier to see than a space: "0000000000", then I add the string I want to right justify "0000000000" + "59.00". I then take the right hand substring of my MAX chars : "0000059.00" .. Use spaces instead of zeros (as i said, not elegant but works everywhere as long as you can add to and substring a string)

Comment: The example only prints 2 decimal numbers, the code examples are totally unrelated and you do not say how `prn_write_text` can be used... Sorry but this question is unclear

Comment: @SouravGhosh Please see the update..How can i do this?

Comment: @Magisch Please see the update..

Comment: @SergeBallesta Please see the update.

Comment: @techno given that this function is not subject to the features of `printf` family functions, it doesn't look like you have a choice but to spam spaces.

Comment: @FreudianSlip Please see the update... I don't know how to implement this with spaces as `strcat` just concatenates  the string with spaces.

Comment: @Magisch I tried... but does not work as intended :(

Comment: @techno what about that doesn'T work? Does it just not print the spaces? Have you done some debug outputting to see if it even appended the spaces?

Comment: @Magisch It prints the spaces(see my code in the answer).. but too many...So is my calculation correct or im i missing something.

Comment: @techno Well, no wonder, you're appending 24 spaces + however many you want. Remove the 24+ at the start of `yyer`'S assignment

Comment: suggest using sprintf() to place each value into an array of char.  using the  '%7.2f' format specifier (other variations could also be used).  then print each string from the same location on each successive line

Comment: @user3629249 Can you please add an example..

Comment: example:  `char output[ 100 ] ={'\0'};`  `sprintf( output, "%7.2f", valuetoPrint );` `prn_write_text( output, strlen(output), 1 );`

Comment: @Evert I don't know why this question is put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

@gsamaras's answer was the way to go. Ok he directly used `printf` when he should have used `snprintf`, but with the only elements given it was already a nice guess.

You can even reuse the buffer if you have many strings to output:

```
char max[20]="";
snprintf(max, 20, "STB Amount:%8s", stbamount);
prn_write_text(max,strlen(max),1);
snprintf(max, 20, "PKG Amount:%8s", pkgamount);
prn_write_text(max,strlen(max),1);
```

---

Let's suppose the length of what you want to print in more than 8 characters, say 16. You must increase the buffer size as well as the print width:

```
char max[28]="";
snprintf(max, 28, "STB Amount:%16s", stbamount);
prn_write_text(max,strlen(max),1);
...
```

The rule here is: size of buffer(28) = size of fix part(11) + size of var(16) + 1(terminating NULL)

Comment: Thanks.... if i have 6 Strings to print... Can i use this approach for all of them?

Comment: But doesn't the buffer `max` contain values already...Im doing `memset(max,0,sizeof(max));`

Comment: @techno: it is *re-used*, meaning that previous values are overwritten. That why my code calls `prn_write_text` before calling `snprintf` again

Comment: Okay... But when the string length increase eg: `STB Balance` the last `0` is cut-off.

Comment: @techno: in that case, you must increase the size of `max` buffer. I always prefere truncating input than silently writing past end of a buffer and invoking undefined behaviour!

Comment: I had upvoted your answer.. but someone down voted.. I tried increasing the buffer size.It does not work either.Actually im using a logic to cut off the float value to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @techno: here is how to increase string length

Comment: Thanks.. Still the last zero is cut-off.Have you seen my update regarding the cutting of decimal points.

Comment: Assuming `balance1` is a double, you can use directly `char max[28]="";
snprintf(max, 28, "STB Amount:%16.2f", balance1);`

Comment: sorry missed that.. updated in question.`balance1` is a float.

Comment: @techno: in `printf` it will silently be promoted to double so it will work the same. I should have said *Assuming balance1 is a float or a double*...

Comment: Thanks... but still the last `0` is being cut-off